# Is there a CloudFormation template for DC/OS, ElasticSearch, Kafka Connect and Kafka Streams?

Tags: elasticsearch, aws-cloudformation, dcos, apache-kafka-streams, apache-kafka-connect

There are a lot of examples of the [SMACK stack](http://bigdata-madesimple.com/smackspark-mesos-akka-kafka/), but in my infrastructure I would like to use ElasticSearch and Confluent Kafka Connect and Kafka Streams.

There is a [great tutorial on deploying a CloudFormation-based SMACK stack environment](https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2016/04/smack-stack-hands/) and another in [creating an IoT pipeline with SMACK](https://dcos.io/docs/1.8/usage/tutorials/iot_pipeline/) as well.

Since I am working on a [Lambda architecture](http://lambda-architecture.net/), I am first starting with my batch data using ElasticSearch (not Cassandra) and would like to know if there are CloudFormation templates that use Kafka Connect, ElasticSearch.  Eventually we want to use Kafka Streams with InfluxDB?

Comment: Questions asking to recommend or find a tutorial or other off-site resource are [off-topic for Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139399/) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

DC/OS has AWS [CloudFormation templates](https://downloads.dcos.io/dcos/stable/aws.html) and [install instructions](https://dcos.io/docs/1.8/administration/installing/cloud/aws/). Once you have DC/OS installed you can install ElasticSearch and Kafka from the Mesosphere Universe as DC/OS packages.